# Is Oracle Database In-Memory an in-memory database?

Tags: oracle, in-memory

Do I need to be able to fit my entire database in memory to us Oracle's Database In-Memory?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can selectively declare a subset of your database to be in-memory. Since Database In-Memory is targeted at analytic workloads it populates selected objects into an in-memory area in columnar format. This allows analytic queries to scan the columnar data much faster than in the row format.